# How do I properly use looping inside ajax deferred object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my script which make use of  parallel ajax request to speed up the data loading.
 
However I'm not sure how to append data inside `#showalltutor div`?

```
results are showing correctly in the php pages because I echoed `json_encode($json);`.
```

But it's not passed to ajax.

```
$(function()
{
    var globalStore;
    var data;
    $.when(
    //fetch first 6 set of data
    $.get("../showAllTutor.php", function(data) {
        globalStore.data = data;
    },'json'),

    // fetch data above 6
     $.get("../showAllTutor2.php", function(data) {
        globalStore.data = data;
    },'json')


).then(function() {

    // All is ready now, so...

     $('#showalltutor').append("<table><tr>");

    var j=0;
     for (i = 0; i < globalStore.data.length; i++) {
          j++;
          $('#showalltutor').append("<td style='padding-right:30px;' id=id_'"+ i +"'><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-10 columns result_container' id='"+globalStore.data[i].postId+"'><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns'><span class='left yellow'>"+mydate+"</span><span class='right'><span class='yellow'>RM "+globalStore.data[i].rate+"</span> hourly</span></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center'><span class='pink'>"+globalStore.data[i].name+"</span></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center'>Rating: <span class='green'>"+globalStore.data[i].plus+"</span> from <span class='reviews'><a id='"+globalStore.data[i].user+"' class='review'>"+globalStore.data[i].total+"reviews</a></span></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-left'>Travels from: <span class='yellow'>"+globalStore.data[i].location+"</span></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns'>Availability: </div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns'><span class='session'>Morning: </span><span class='yellow'>"+globalStore.data[i].morning+"</span><span class='session'> Afternoon: </span><span class='yellow'>"+globalStore.data[i].afternoon+"</span><span class='session'> Evening: </span><span class='yellow'>"+globalStore.data[i].evening+"</span></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-left'>Contact<span class='session'>(click to show)</span>:<a href='tel:"+ globalStore.data[i].contact+"' onclick='click_log(\""+globalStore.data[i].postId+","+globalStore.data[i].subid+"\")'><span class='green contact'>"+globalStore.data[i].contact+"</span></a></div></div></td>");

     }
      $('#showalltutor').append("</table>");

});
});
```

Example of PHP script that passes data as array to the ajax req to be displayed.

```
 <?php
  $Tutor = new searchItems();
  $showAllTutor = $Tutor->showAllTutor($name);
  $json=array();
  foreach($showAllTutor as $key=>$value)
  {
      $total = $value['plus']+ $value['neg'];
     array_push($json,array("name"=>$value["name"],"subject"=>$value["subject"],"rate"=>$value['rate'],"dateposted"=>$value['dateposted'],"location"=>$value['location'],"contact"=>$value['contact'],"morning"=>$value['morning'],"afternoon"=>$value['afternoon'],"evening"=>$value['evening'],"postId"=>$value['postId'],"subid"=>$value['subid'],"total"=>$total,"plus"=>$value['plus'],"user"=>$value['user']));
  }
 echo json_encode($json);
  ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean the data is not being passed to `AJAX`? You are stating these requests are expecting JSON, so make sure you are sending `JSON` and nothing else (otherwise the requests will fail and your `.then` will not be executed). Easy thing to do is to remove your closing `?>` to make sure that you aren't returning whitespace that ruins the JSON formatting.

Comment: Quite sure in your example above, you're overwriting globalStore.data, so it will only ever hold 6 sets of data, depending on which finishes last. Use globalStore.data.push(data) instead. (And define globalStore.data = [] before)

Comment: @DrunkWolf, thanks for that

Comment: So assuming the whole .when().then() is working, i'm guessing your problem is in how to actually create a nice table out of all of this?

Comment: @DrunkWolf, no it's not working yet...I still unable to append data in $.then

Comment: Is the site 'live'? as in, can i check the actual url to see if it's running proper json?

Comment: @Adam, I removed the closing ?> in both php scripts and used $.trim(data); in ajax before assignign to global.data. The status of req for both php script is 200 means OK, but it's not showing in the div where it should show.

Comment: @DrunkWolf, it's not live..MAybe you're right..I suspect the data type in json which I defined as json..Actually I don't know how to specify it in $.get but in php script I did properly encoded data as json as I tested before making parallel req and it worked.

Comment: @Adam what do you get if in the $.get's you console.log(data)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89177/discussion-between-drunkwolf-and-vani).

Comment: If `.then` isn't getting executed, then you're returning improperly formatted `JSON`. This could by something like extra whitespace, or a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of your PHP file. You also should not be using `globalData` and instead the results will be passed in as arguments to your `.then` function as I have illustrated in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The resolved data are passed as separate arguments to your `.then` function

```
$.when(
    $.get(url1,'json'),
    $.get(url2,'json'),
).then(function(resp1,resp2) {
   console.log(resp1);
   console.log(resp2);
   ...
});
```

Worth noting that these AJAX requests are being performed in parallel, as you state, but the `.then` callback will not be executed until **both** of the requests are finished (that's how `$.when` works), so I'm not sure how this will offer your users any speed advantages.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use my example with this..Could you please show?  Can I replace  req1 = "../showAllTutor.php" and how to retrieve json data and append please?